# Multiple joins, show one value if it occurs more than once

Tags: sql

Say I have 3 tables below:

**Table1 t1**

```
id  c1     c2
 1  Jon    Doe
 2  James  SMith
 3  jolly  rancher
```

**Table2 t2**

```
id  c1
 1  addr_1
 1  addr_2
 2  addr_1
 2  addr_2
 3  addr_1
```

**Table3 t3**

```
id  c1
 1  phone_1
 2  phone_1
 3  phone_1
 3  phone_2
```

What i am trying to get is this:

```
1  Jon    Doe      addr_1  phone_1
1                  addr_2
2  James  SMith    addr_1  phone_1
2                  addr_2
3  jolly  rancher  addr_1  phone_1
3                          phone_2
```

So that id is there for each output but other fields only once per that grouping—is this possible?

Comment: This would be _much_ to do in the app/reporting layer.  SQL isn't great at suppressing repeating values.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible? Yes.  Is it ideal? Not really.  I have to agree with D Stanley that it is definitely better to handle something like this in the app/reporting layer if you can.

However, if you really wanted to do this in SQL, you can see my solution below or go to the [SQL fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/525fb/1).  This solution is not ideal because it's only working off the sample data you provided. If you have data where there are at least 2 phone numbers and at least 2 addresses for a given person, then the SQL below would need to be modified to handle that scenario.  I've renamed the tables and columns to something a little more meaningful so that it's easier to read.

```
create table person(
  id int,
  firstName varchar(20),
  lastName varchar(20)
  )

create table address(
  id int,
  addr varchar(20)
  )

create table phonenumber(
  id int,
  phoneNum varchar(20)
  )

insert person (id, firstName, lastName)select 1, 'jon', 'doe'
insert person (id, firstName, lastName)select 2, 'james', 'smith'
insert person (id, firstName, lastName)select 3, 'jolly', 'rancher'

insert address(id, addr)select 1, 'addr_1'
insert address(id, addr)select 1, 'addr_2'
insert address(id, addr)select 2, 'addr_1'
insert address(id, addr)select 2, 'addr_2'
insert address(id, addr)select 3, 'addr_1'

insert phonenumber(id, phoneNum)select 1, 'phone_1'
insert phonenumber(id, phoneNum)select 2, 'phone_1'
insert phonenumber(id, phoneNum)select 3, 'phone_1'
insert phonenumber(id, phoneNum)select 3, 'phone_2'

CREATE TABLE #results(
  id int,
  firstName varchar(20),
  lastName varchar(20),
  address varchar(20),
  phoneNumber varchar(20)
  )

CREATE TABLE #finalresults(
  id int,
  firstName varchar(20),
  lastName varchar(20),
  address varchar(20),
  phoneNumber varchar(20)
  )

INSERT #results
  (
  id, firstName, lastName, address, phoneNumber
  )
SELECT Person.id, Person.firstName, Person.lastName, address.addr, phonenumber.phoneNum
FROM Person
INNER JOIN address
  ON person.id = address.id
INNER JOIN phonenumber
  ON person.id = phonenumber.id

DECLARE @id int, @firstname varchar(20), @lastname varchar(20),
  @address varchar(20), @phonenumber varchar(20)

DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR
  FOR SELECT * FROM #results
OPEN my_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor INTO @id, @firstname, @lastname, @address, @phonenumber

while @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #finalresults WHERE id = @id)
  BEGIN
    INSERT #finalresults(id, firstname, lastname, address, phonenumber)
    SELECT @id, @firstname, @lastname, @address, @phonenumber
  END  
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    INSERT #finalresults(id, firstname, lastname, address, phonenumber)
    SELECT distinct @id, '', '',
            CASE WHEN finalAddress.address IS NOT NULL
            THEN ''
            ELSE @address
            END,
            CASE WHEN finalPhoneNumber.phonenumber IS NOT NULL
            THEN ''
            ELSE @phonenumber
            END
    FROM #finalresults
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #finalresults finalAddress
      ON finalAddress.id = @id
      AND finalAddress.address = @address
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #finalresults finalPhoneNumber
      ON finalPhoneNumber.id = @id
      AND finalPhoneNumber.phonenumber = @phonenumber
  END

  FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor INTO @id, @firstname, @lastname, @address, @phonenumber

END

CLOSE my_cursor
DEALLOCATE my_cursor

SELECT * FROM #finalresults
```